# How to copy and paste entire column conditionally using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy and paste columns automatically that fit a certain criteria. My code currently analyzes the condition correctly, but I haven't been able to get it to copy / paste the corresponding column. Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is - if row #1 contains today's date - copy and paste the entire column as a value to get rid of the formulas. I currently have the code below:

```
Dim K As String
  K = Date
  MsgBox K

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 9
    If (Cells(1, i).Value = K) Then Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy
    Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial
    
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to copy the entire row (as mentioned in the title of your question) or the entire column (as indicated in the code you provided)?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - column.. Sorry. I need to copy/paste the entire column when the condition of the row is met.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
Dim K As String
  K = Date
  MsgBox K

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 9
    If (Cells(1, i).Value < K) Then Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy
    Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next i
```